# get content inside <article > tag with jsoup in android

Tags: android, jsoup

how to get content inside  tag with jsoup in android ?

I have searched long and hard but found nothing that helped yet. I really do not know what to do. I wrote all the details below. I've tried and did not succeed.

my html code :

```
<div id="content-post">
<article class="post clearfix">
<figure class="post-image"></figure>
<header></header>
        Line 1
        Line 2
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 4
        Line 5
        Line 6
        Line 7
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 8
        Line 9
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 10
        Line 11
<p></p>
<div class="news_detail">
<div class="news_soc"></div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

I need to take line 1 to line 11.
I want to put them into an array.

**update :**

```
<div id="content-post">
<article class="post clearfix">
<figure class="post-image">
<img src="../../../../../upload/news/2014/07/large/JuiR1404499837lucxqg.jpg" />
<h1>Agree</h1>
</figure>
<header>
<p class="post-meta">2014</p>
</header>        Line 1
        Line 2
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 4
        Line 5
        Line 6
        Line 7
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 8
        Line 9
<br></br>
<br></br>
        Line 10
        Line 11
<p></p>
<div class="news_detail">
<div class="news_soc">
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?" target="_blank"><img alt="Google+" src="../../../../theme/image/soc_gp.jpg"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet/" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" src="../../../../theme/image/soc_tw.jpg"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" src="../../../../theme/image/soc_fb.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div class="news_auth">
        Send By Jack
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

my code :

```
 int timeOut = 30 * 1000;// 30 second.
                String url =CommonMethods.getCurrentSite() + URLEncoder.encode(news.getLink(), "UTF-8").replace("%2F","/");
                _doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                        .timeout(timeOut)
                        .get();
                if (isCancelled()) { // If Cancel Read Content News return Null
                    return null;
                }
                _ContentRegion = _doc.getElementById("content-post");

//I really do not know what to do.
```

Comment: Is this how the HTML always look? Are `<div class="news_detail">` and `<div class="news_soc">` always empty?

Comment: update question. no. Are never empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found :

```
_ContentRegion = _doc.getElementById("content-post").select("article > p");
                 for (Element ee : _ContentRegion){
                    Log.d("ownText",ee.ownText());
                }
```